# CSS3 animation: is it possible for a child div to have opposite rotation to a parent div?

Tags: css, animation

EDIT:
I have changed it slightly so that they are squares rather than circles as it was pointed out that it would be easier to understand what I mean

https://jsfiddle.net/i7708974/k3ebq7j0/

ORIGINAL:
I've been playing around with CSS3 animations for a project I'm doing however I think my logic is wrong.

I needed to do two things, create a series of eight rotating circles orbiting and set it so that when you hover over any of the eight circles they would pause and remain in the same orientation they were in when the page opened.

I managed to set the eight circles orbiting however haven't been able to figure out how to stop each individual circle from rotating its orientation.

I don't know if this is possible however after days of trying decided to see if anyone here can help me, below is a jsfiddle link to the code (if you hover over one of the circles you should see quarter of it highlighted and change orientation every time you move the mouse off and back over again).

https://jsfiddle.net/i7708974/xs7mcgdd/

I have tried two methods to change the orientation however they don't seem to do anything..

```
.Rm, .Tm, .P, .Sc, .Sf, .D, .R, .A{
-webkit-animation: wrapper 15s linear infinite normal;
-moz-animation: wrapper 15s linear infinite normal;
-ms-animation: wrapper 15s linear infinite normal;
-o-animation: wrapper 15s linear infinite normal;
animation: wrapper 15s linear infinite normal;
}
```

and..

```
.Rm, .Tm, .P, .Sc, .Sf, .D, .R, .A{
-webkit-animation: none;
-moz-animation: none;
-ms-animation: none;
-o-animation: none;
animation: none;
}
```

Comment: i think its better you let them as squares to people understand/visualize it easier;

Comment: That's a very good point, I shall do that now.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let them inside a container spinning in one direction, while each one goes in the opposite direction:

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;  
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border: 4px solid lightblue;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#container div {  
  width:20px;
  height: 20px;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: example2;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#a1 {
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
}

#a2 {
  top:5px;
  left:calc(50% - 10px);
}

#a3 {
  top: 30px;
  left:calc(100% - 50px);
}

#a4 {
  top:calc( 50% - 10px);
  left:calc(100% - 25px);
}

#a5 {
  top:calc(100% - 50px);
  left:calc(100% - 50px);
}

#a6 {
  top:calc( 100% - 25px);
  left:calc( 50% - 10px);
}

#a7 {
  top:calc( 100% - 50px);
  left: 30px;
}

#a8 {
  top:calc( 50% - 10px);
  left:5px;
}

@keyframes example {
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes example2 {
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

img {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}

#container:hover, #container:hover div {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<div id=a1><img src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png" alt=star></div>
<div id=a2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png" alt=star></div>
<div id=a3><img src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png" alt=star></div>
<div id=a4><img src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png" alt=star></div>
<div id=a5><img src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png" alt=star></div>
<div id=a6><img src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png" alt=star></div>
<div id=a7><img src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png" alt=star></div>
<div id=a8><img src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png" alt=star></div>
</div>
```

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOgOWb?editors=1100)

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant! I did have one question however, if you add

#container:hover{
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

the squares continue to spin in the opposite direction, is there a way to make sure they are completly paused?

Comment: Okay then, thank you for all of you help and advice! :)

Comment: @C.Marks pen **and** snipped updated working 100% - recheck please;

Comment: Amazing! All I had ever heard about stackoverflow was bad but every time I ask a question there are some brilliant responses! thanks :)

Comment: your `transform: rotate(Xdeg) + translate(Xpx) + rotate(-Xdeg);` technique was useful to me on [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078513/custom-loading-icon-using-pure-css-html5); thank you very much