# Custom loading icon using pure CSS HTML5

Tags: html, css, animation

This is I want to create:

[image]

The image contains one outer circle and one inner triangle, and loading effect on outer circle should be anticlockwise and on inner triangle should be Clockwise.

I have created outer circle using this:

```css
.loader { 
 position: relative; 
 border-top: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); 
 border-right: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); 
 border-bottom: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); 
 border-left: 1.1em solid #ffffff; transform: translateZ(0); 
 animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear; 
} 
 
.loader, .loader:after { 
 border-radius: 50%; 
 width: 10em; 
 height: 10em; 
} 

@keyframes load8 { 
 0% { 
  transform: rotate(0deg); 
 } 

 100% { 
  transform: rotate(360deg); 
 } 
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Comment: where is your tried code?

Comment: Edit your question and put above code in your question ..

Comment: Added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer a community wiki post. The distance between the dots on the circle is being made by their position, while in the 'play' symbol, it is being made by the animation delay (before of it starts).

[**Codepen DEMO**](http://codepen.io/freestock/pen/xVgvvE?editors=1100)

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) inset;
}

#innercontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto ;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;  
}

#container .a2 {  
  width:20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -10px;
}

#container .a1 {
  position: absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  animation-name: example2a;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#container .a {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0s;  
}

#container .b {
  opacity: 0.9;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0.08s;  
}

#container .c {
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0.17s;  
}

#container .d {
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0.27s;  
}

#container .ab {
  opacity: 0.6;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0.38s;  
}

#container .bb {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0.50s;  
}

#container .cb {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0.63s;  
}

#container .db {
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0.77s;  
}

#container .ac {
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0.92s;  
}

#container .bc {
  opacity: 0.1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 1.08s;  
}

#play {
  position: absolute;
  width:0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 115px solid white;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  opacity: 0.2;
  left: 48px;
  top: 50px;
}

.w {
  transform: rotate(270deg)
  translate(100px) rotate(-270deg);
  opacity: 1;
}

.x {
  transform: rotate(280deg)
  translate(100px) rotate(-280deg);
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.y {
  transform: rotate(291deg)
  translate(100px) rotate(-291deg);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.z {
  transform: rotate(303deg)
  translate(100px) rotate(-303deg);
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.wb {
  transform: rotate(316deg)
  translate(100px) rotate(-316deg);
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.xb {
  transform: rotate(330deg)
  translate(100px) rotate(-330deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.yb {
  transform: rotate(346deg)
  translate(100px) rotate(-346deg);
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.zb {
  transform: rotate(363deg)
  translate(100px) rotate(-363deg);
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.wc {
  transform: rotate(381deg)
  translate(100px) rotate(-381deg);
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.xc {
  transform: rotate(400deg)
  translate(100px) rotate(-400deg);
  opacity: 0.1;
}

@keyframes example {
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes example2a {

  33.3% {
  top:calc( 50% - 10px);
  left:calc(100% - 25px);
  }
  
  
  66.6% {
  top:calc( 100% - 50px);
  left: 30px;
  }  
  
  
  100% {
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<div class="a1 a"></div><div class="a1 b"></div>
<div class="a1 c"></div><div class="a1 d"></div>
<div class="a1 ab"></div><div class="a1 bb"></div>
<div class="a1 cb"></div><div class="a1 db"></div>
<div class="a1 ac"></div><div class="a1 bc"></div>
<div id=play></div>
<div id=innercontainer>
<div class="a2 w"></div><div class="a2 x"></div>
<div class="a2 y"></div><div class="a2 z"></div>
<div class="a2 wb"></div><div class="a2 xb"></div>
<div class="a2 yb"></div><div class="a2 zb"></div>
<div class="a2 wc"></div><div class="a2 xc"></div>
</div>
</div>
```